# VsCode terminal is running extremely slow

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL (Ubuntu) subsystem on windows; any and all commands I run inside the terminal of VsCode, lags by at least five seconds. However, when I run commands in the Ubuntu terminal it runs smoothly.